# Quoting articles of laws(ex. usage of "stipulate", "specify")

Tags: expressions, sentence, writing

> Article 15 of the Korean Constitution states that “all citizens shall
>   enjoy the freedom of choice of occupation.” Compared to Article 12 of
>   the Basic Law, which comprises of three clauses, Article 15 of the
>   Korean Constitution consists of only one sentence and does not ***specify***
>   exercise of occupation.

When I write a research paper, I frequently quote or refer to articles or provisions (of laws).

I feel I use same expressions repetitively and feel sometimes my expression sound weird.

For example, in the sentence above, which would be proper expression between "specify" and "stipulate"?

Comment: Asking for an opinion on which is proper may be off-topic. This question seems more suited to [Writing.SE]. Worth migrating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Stipulation" is a legal term. It means to agree to something, either to a term of a contract or to an undisputed fact. "Stipulation" requires opposing parties.

If you are quoting a law, just "state" or "specify" is better, since "stipulation" is a legal term of art.

Writing about law is frequently repetitive. The repetition is for clarity.